# Accessing a Imagefile and Bind it to Image in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I was wondering how to set the ImageSource of this image created from this code:

```
var createfolder = await picturesFolder.CreateFolderAsync("cakeimages", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await picturesFolder.GetFolderAsync("cakeimages");
var outputfile = await file.CopyAsync(picturesFolder, newfilename + i+ file.FileType, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

i copied an image file to the local folder and renamed it according to my code. how can i bind the source of that image to the Image?

Comment: Set the `Source` of the image to a new ImageSource or BitmapImage via the file's URI.